# Multithreading socket connections C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

Hello StackOverFlow community, i'm working on a C# program which depends on many sockets connection for the same server.
I would like to do multithreading on my connection classes so i will be able to create as many connections as i want without creating many classes
However Code will explain it abit:
Gateway(Connection Thread)

```
using SilkroadSecurityApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleLogin1
{
    public class Gateway
    {
        public static MainClass MainWindow;
        public static ServerEnum Server = ServerEnum.None;
        public static List<Packet> GatewayPackets = new List<Packet>();
        public static TransferBuffer GatewayRecvBuffer = new TransferBuffer(0x1000, 0, 0);
        public static Security GatewaySecurity = new Security();
        public static Socket GatewaySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        public static Thread loop;
        public enum ServerEnum
        {
            None,
            Gateway,
            Agent
        }
        public void Gateway_thread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                SocketError success;
                byte[] bytes;
                GatewayRecvBuffer.Size = GatewaySocket.Receive(GatewayRecvBuffer.Buffer, 0, GatewayRecvBuffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, out success);
                if (success != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    if (success != SocketError.WouldBlock)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if (GatewayRecvBuffer.Size > 0)
                {
                    GatewaySecurity.Recv(GatewayRecvBuffer);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
                List<Packet> collection = GatewaySecurity.TransferIncoming();
                if (collection != null)
                {
                    GatewayPackets.AddRange(collection);
                }
                if (GatewayPackets.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Packet packet in GatewayPackets)
                    {
                        //incoming packets
                    }
                    GatewayPackets.Clear();
                }
                List<KeyValuePair<TransferBuffer, Packet>> list2 = GatewaySecurity.TransferOutgoing();
                if (list2 != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<TransferBuffer, Packet> pair in list2)
                    {
                        TransferBuffer key = pair.Key;
                        Packet packet = pair.Value;
                        success = SocketError.Success;
                        while (key.Offset != key.Size)
                        {
                            int num19 = GatewaySocket.Send(key.Buffer, key.Offset, key.Size - key.Offset, SocketFlags.None, out success);
                            if ((success != SocketError.Success) && (success != SocketError.WouldBlock))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            key.Offset += num19;
                            Thread.Sleep(1);
                        }
                        if (success != SocketError.Success)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        bytes = packet.GetBytes();
                    }
                    if (success != SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        public static void SendToServer(Packet packet)
        {
            GatewaySecurity.Send(packet);
        }

        public void Connect(string IP, string Port)
        {
            loop = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Gateway_thread));
            GatewaySocket.Connect(IP, int.Parse(Port));
            loop.Start();
            GatewaySocket.Blocking = false;
            GatewaySocket.NoDelay = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SilkroadSecurityApi;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleLogin1
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public string ip = "25.122.17.189";
        public string port = "15779";
        public string locale = "22";
        public string version = "190";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new MainClass().Start();
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            Gateway.MainWindow = this;
            new Gateway().Connect(ip, port);
        }
    }
}
```

However i have tried many ways such as:

```
Gateway G1 = new Gateway();  
Gateway G2 = new Gateway();
```

also starting new threads

```
Thread G1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Gateway.Connect))
Thread G2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Gateway.Connect))
```

but no way,can't ever create new GatewaySocket while there is already an open connections.
anyway my question again is: How i can do multithreading for Gateway and each one got it's own connection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't create multiple sockets for the same port at the same time.  You'll need to have each socket listening to a different port.

Comment: if you start listening to a port. it is locked for every socket in .NET. you can do a workaround with the WinAPI, but thats another untold Story

Comment: @Servy there is no a better way and faster to do it ?

Comment: @BugsBunny There most certainly are better ways to run a server than what you're doing.  Creating two threads two each create separate sockets simply isn't it.  How to create a well designed server application is well beyond the scope of what can be described in an SO answer.

Comment: @BugsBunny what is your application about? what do you want to achieve with multiple connection? also every "connection" would receive the same data

Comment: @Servy i'm not creating a server.. i'm connecting to an exists network.

Comment: @SebastianL what i want to achieve is bot which log in to a game with many accounts and each account do a different work,ofc not the same data. each connection will receive and send a different packets.

Comment: @BugsBunny Client then, same difference.

Comment: @BugsBunny you have to use a single connection. I'll provide a possible solution as answer, but that could take a while ;)

Comment: @Servy Show an example please,P.S. SilkroadSecurity is API in .net 4.0 (C#) which made for sending and receive packets into Silkroad private servers, it supports both client and server security processing.
so i'm not sure changing my way would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Soo here is how i would do it:

1. I would define various classes:

   - Connection
   - Command
   - ActionController
   - GUI
2. The Connection class:

   ```
   public class Connection
   {
       public string ip = "";
       public string port = "";
       public bool listening = false;

       public TcpClient tcpClient;
       private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
       private NetworkStream stream;

       public delegate DataReceivedEvent(Byte[] data, TcpEventArgs e);
       public DataReceivedEvent dataReceived;

       public List<Command> commands = new List<Command>();

       //for Debugging purpose
       public string lastError = "";

       public Connection(string ip, string port)
       {
           this.ip = ip;
           this.port = port;
           bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

           if(!Connect())
           {
               return;
               //maybe do something here?
           }                
       }

       public bool Connect()
       {
           try
           {
               tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);
               stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
               return true;
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               lastError = ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace;
               return false;
           }
       }

       public void BeginListening()
       {
           bw.DoWork += listenToNetwork();
           bw.RunWorkerAsync();
       }

       public void EndListening()
       {
           bw.CancelAsync();
       }

       private void listenToNetwork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
           while(!PendingCancellation)
           {
               Byte[] bytes = new Byte[preferedLenghth];
               listening = true;
               Int32 bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
               if(dataReceived != null)
               {
                   dataReceived(bytes, new TcpEventArgs(bytesRead));
               }
           }
           listening = false;
       }

       public void SendCommands()
       {
           foreach(Command cmd in commands)
           {
               cmd.Execute(ref stream);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. The Command class:

   ```
   // i made a seperate class of Command because it is easy to expand without getting monsterclasse
   public class Command
   {
       private CommandEnum cmd;

       public Command(CommandEnum cmd)
       {
           this.cmd = cmd;
       }

       public void Execute(ref NetworkStream stream)
       {
           switch(cmd)
           {
               //insert commands like stream.write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
               default:
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. The ActionController class:

   ```
   public ActionController
   {
       public Connection conn;

       public ActionController(string ip, string port)
       {
           conn = new Connection(ip, port)
           conn.dataReceived += dataReceivedevent;
       }

       public void dataReceivedevent(Byte[] data, TcpEventArgs e)
       {
            //Do something with the received data here
       }
       //Do everything here! the Controller is here to provide necessary information for the GUI
   }
   ```

   .5 The GUI is upon your imagination ;)

I think the code is kind of self-explanatory ask if something is unclear

Comment: Sorry Sebastian but this won't even connect into the game server itself of silkroad. somehow silkroad game server and client are differently made for connections even there is a port for logging and another port for playing..

Comment: @Bugs Bunny then use two connections with different ports, you just have to create two instances of Connection